# Streaming analytics using Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, cassandra, apache-kafka

We are collecting streaming data from device (Android , iOS). The data flow is , websocket -> logstash -> kafka -> spark -> cassandra. Ram is of 16 GB. Our app is based on OTT platform and when a video is streaming it will send events to kafka for analytics purpose. Current situation is, memory will be overflowed quickly while playing 4 or 5 videos in parallel.

What might be the issue? Is it any configuration mistake? Is there any other better approach for our requirement?

Comment: You're running this all on a single 16GB machine?

Comment: Yes. Initially we used  single 16 GB and later upgraded to 32 GB AWS

Comment: So Kafka, Spark, Cassandra etc are all distributed systems. You can scale them out for both resilience (which I hope you are already considering!) but also performance/throughput as required.

Comment: we are now running kafka and spark streaming in separate servers. So kafka is stable now. My doubt is, Am I following correct architecture? Can my system handle more than 10,000 user activities at a time with this architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your broad question with a broad answer.

> Is Logstash / Kafka / Spark / Cassandra a 'correct' architecture?

There's nothing particularly wrong with that approach. It depends on what processing you're doing, and why you're landing it to Cassandra. You'll find plenty of people taking this approach, whilst others may use different stream processing e.g. Kafka Streams, as well as not always using a data store (since Apache Kafka persists data) - depends on what's consuming the data afterwards.

> Can my system handle more than 10,000 user activities at a time with this architecture?

Yes. No. It depends, on way too many factors to give an answer. 10,000 users doing a simple activity with small volumes of data is hugely different from 10,000 users requiring complex processing on large volumes of data.

The only way to get an answer to this, and evaluate your architectural choice in general, is to analyse the behaviour of your system as you increase [simulated] user numbers. Do particular bottlenecks appear that indicate the requirement for greater hardware scale, or even different technology choices.

Comment: Thank you so much.  We will analyse it on a test environment.